# Is there any ways that I can export only the changed files in one commit in git?

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using gerrit as my code review and git system.
And now I am trying to get only the files of a certain patchset in gerrit,excluding the other files in git repository.
Is there any way to do this,like a git command or sth ?

For instance ,[Here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/59951/) is a patchset ,Now I want download only the nine files changed in this commit, What can I do to make it?

Comment: your question does not seem to make much sense. what exactly do you want?

Comment: I've update the question trying to make it clear.

Comment: gerrit is not gitweb. it may provide you patches, but does not necessarily provide you full copies of files, ever. you still need to `repo sync` or `git pull` to get your files. in that case, just use local git commands to get what you need, no reason to download anything from gerrit web inteface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the question is exactly about. Maybe you are looking for:

```
git log --name-only
```

In git there is no "download". You only clone a complete repository and fetch new commits afterwards.

Once you have a local clone of the repository you are able access all files ever created in that repository.

If you want the content of a file in a given commit you can say something like:

```
git show a90b68ab485d795d3fb1f5220eb7851b21583ccd:sources/host-tools/gdb-pretty-printers/stlport/gppfs-0.2/COPYING
```

Comment: Thks, Can copy the nine files to another folder using git command ?

Comment: No, `git` is not for copying files. - But `cp` is. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using the gerrit query command?

You can use `ssh -p 29418 user@gerrit.example.com gerrit query --current-patch-set 123 --files`

This give you the list of files that have change for that patchset 123. It is possible to format the output as JSON for easier processing.

For more details see the [documentation](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/cmd-query.html).

Comment: Although gerrit query is useful, this doesn't give you the contents of the files. It will tell you which files have been added/modified/deleted. It can also give you the size of the change. But it doesn't give you the actual file.